Unable to trigger selenium scripts on selenium grid, working on local
I am running selenium python script through Selenium Grid, but it throws error

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to find resource, invalid path in url."

Below is Webdriver setup file
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import os

class WebDriverSetup:
    def __init__(self, grid_url, window_size="1920,1080", device_scale_factor="1", timeout=100):
        self.grid_url = grid_url # URL of the Selenium Grid hub
        self.path = r"path to driver.exe" 
        self.window_size = window_size
        self.device_scale_factor = device_scale_factor
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.driver = None
        self.wait = None

    def start_driver(self):
        # Set up Edge options
        print(self.grid_url)
        print(self.path)
        edge_options = Options()
        edge_options.add_argument(f"--force-device-scale-factor={self.device_scale_factor}")
        
        # Set download directory preferences
        download_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "downloads")
        if not os.path.exists(download_dir):
            os.makedirs(download_dir)
        edge_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
            "download.default_directory": download_dir,
            "download.prompt_for_download": False,
            "download.directory_upgrade": True,
        })

        # Create a remote WebDriver instance
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor=self.grid_url,
            options=edge_options,
            # desired_capabilities=edge_options.to_capabilities()
        )

        # Maximize the browser window
        self.driver.maximize_window()

        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.timeout)

        return self.driver, self.wait
    
    def set_timeout(self, timeout):
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.timeout)
        # Example of changing timeout
        # webdriver_setup.set_timeout(200) in test file

    def stop_driver(self):
        if self.driver:
            self.driver.quit()

This is my test script
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
from utilities.webdriver_setup import WebDriverSetup  # Assuming your WebDriverSetup class is in webdriver_setup.py

grid_url = "http://localhost:4444/ui/"

webdriver_setup = WebDriverSetup(grid_url)

try:
    driver = None
    # Start WebDriver session on Selenium Grid
    driver, wait = webdriver_setup.start_driver()
    print("Driver started successfully")

    # Example: Navigate to a website
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
    print(f"Title: {driver.title}")

    # Your test logic here

finally:
    # Ensure driver is stopped even if an exception occurs
    if driver:
        webdriver_setup.stop_driver()


Selenium grid : 4.22.0
Python : 3.10

I have ran the case on local but not able to trigger on selenium grid, throws me error selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to find resource, invalid path in url..

Drop the /ui from http://localhost:4444/ui/ and try again? The url seems to be invalid.

Thanks Rishabh Jain. Can you please mark my answer as accepted and close this question.

It is because http://localhost:4444/ui is pointing to the web interface of the selenium grid and not the path required to establish a selenium session. Hence, you'll need to remove /ui from the mentioned url.
grid_url = "http://localhost:4444/"
webdriver_setup = WebDriverSetup(grid_url)

